# ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:1007)

Tags: python, ssl, kafka-python

```
producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers='kafka.XXXX.dev:9093',
    security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
    sasl_mechanism='PLAIN',
    sasl_plain_username=sasl_plain_username,  
    sasl_plain_password=sasl_plain_password, 
    ssl_cafile='/path/to/CARoot.pem',
    ssl_certfile='/path/to/certificate.pem',
    ssl_keyfile='/path/to/Private_key.pem',
    value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8')
)
```

The above producer gives me `ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:1007)`

`ssl_cafile` is pem generated from the truststore.jks with alias CAROOT

`ssl_certfile` is certificate pem generated from keystore.jks with alias localhost

`ssl_keyfile` is private key pem generated from keystore.jks with alias localhost

Is there anything wrong with the configuration?.

I tried to regenerate all pem files with

```
keytool -exportcert -alias $alias -keystore $keyStore -rfc -file $outputFolder/certificate.pem -storepass $password


keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore $keyStore -srcalias $alias -destkeystore $outputFolder/cert_and_key.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -storepass $password -srcstorepass $password
openssl pkcs12 -in $outputFolder/cert_and_key.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out $outputFolder/key.pem -passin pass:$password


keytool -exportcert -alias $alias -keystore $trusttore -rfc -file $outputFolder/CARoot.pem -storepass $password
```

but got same result.